# How can i create a global php variable that can be accessed from any file

Tags: php

So i created a navbar and add code similar to this, and here is what i have,

```
<ul>

some links

</ul>

<?php

if logedin == true) {
echo "you are loged in";
} else {
echo "please log in";
}

</nav>
```

now the other part of this code in another file called account.php,this isnt the real code i have but this is something im using to demonstrate,

```
$logedin = true;
```

but the code doesn't work and and the variable doesn't show on the fist page (the code on the top).
what can i do?
Thanks!

(EDIT) i forgot to say this, but the navbar is on more than 1 page and that the problem , and idk how to use post on more than 1 page.

Comment: You will probably benefit greatly from writing your code with syntax highlighting. Your snippet is full of syntax (and spelling) errors.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: oh ok ill try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value that indicates whether someone is logged in or not would be best stored in the Session - then it will persist between requests to different scripts (by the same user), but not permanently.

e.g.

**login.php**

When the user has successfully logged in, set a variable

```
<?php
session_start(); //access the session

//...some code here to check username / password etc, and then if they are all ok, you can set them as logged in for the duration of the session....

$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true; //store a variable in the session
```

Then in **home.php**, when the user visits this page you can check the session to see if they logged in successfully or not:

```
<?php
session_start();
$loggedIn = $_SESSION["loggedin"];

//if not logged in, redirect back to the login page and end the script
if ($loggedIn == false) {
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit();
}

//otherwise, continue as normal...
```

There's a comprehensive explanation of how sessions work [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839).